# Is it possible to create a userspace networking stack with python?

Tags: python, networking, kernel, userspace

Looking to create a project which implements a *user-space networking stack*, so that a user space application has access to the network cards, I've never done this before and I was wondering if it would possible to get this close to the hardware using a language like *python* and, if not, which language would be best?

Comment: OS tend to frown on such attempts, for both security and efficiency reasons.

Comment: This might be too broad/vague, and possibly off topic. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly possible to do, but depending on how far down you want to go, you will need to write some parts in another language. The authors of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.10664.pdf) [1] wrote a version of their user-space network driver [in Python](https://github.com/ixy-languages/ixy-languages), but they used Cython for external memory management.

While using Python for this is probably possible, Python is much slower than many other languages. The authors of the paper I mentioned [implemented their driver in 10 languages and compared them](https://github.com/ixy-languages/ixy-languages), and Python was the slowest—10 times slower than the next-slowest (but they do note (in [2]) that all of their drivers *except* the Python driver were optimized for performance).

Generally speaking, if you want to learn how to do systems programming, I recommend doing it in a systems language, like C or Rust. Traditionally, this type of code would most-often be written in C. If you want arguments in favor of using languages besides C, the same authors wrote [this paper](https://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/papers/the-case-for-writing-network-drivers-in-high-level-languages.pdf) [2], which discusses why you would want to use higher-level languages (from Rust to Python) for writing a network driver.

In short, Python probably isn't the best language for this if you want it to be more than a toy project, but if you want to do it, the Python code from those papers is probably a good place to start on the lowest-level parts; in fact, the authors hoped to be helpful to others [2]:

> We provide primitives for PCIe driver development in Python that we hope to be helpful to others as this is the first PCIe driver in Python to our knowledge.

---

1. P. Emmerich, M. Pudelko, S. Bauer, S. Huber, T. Zwickl, and G. Carle,
   "User Space Network Drivers,"
   in ACM/IEEE Symposium on Architectures for Networking and Communications Systems (ANCS 2019), 2019.
   [arXiv:1901.10664](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10664) [cs.NI]
2. P. Emmerich, S. Ellmann, F. Bonk, A. Egger, E. G. Sánchez-Torija, T. Günzel, S. Di Luzio, A. Obada, M. Stadlmeier, S. Volt, and G. Carle,
   "The Case for Writing Network Drivers in High-Level Programming Languages,"
   in ANCS 2019.
   [arXiv:1909.06344](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06344) [cs.NI]